# Where can you rest in Heathsong/Elm's Reach/Twin Elms

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

In Pillar's of Eternity there does not seem to be an inn in Twin Elms ?

How can you heal ?

Answer (score 12):

The Celestial Sapling Inn is located in the southeastern corner of the Hearthsong district. Talk to the Ogre down there who will bring you up to the inn on the lift.